# How to get a slug in Ruby on Rails and use it as body class for the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, get, slug

I'm a noob in Ruby, and I have this project where I really need pages to have unique classes/ids. That would be very convenient for stying.

Each page on the website has a slug. Like [www.site.com/page-slug](http://www.site.com/page-slug)

So I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to get that page slug and assign it to that page's body. Then I can just go ahead and create unique styles for that page.

I could do this with JavaScript, but I'd rather do it with Ruby on Rails if that's possible.

I haven't really tried anything yet, because I'm not qualified enough. I'm looking for general and/or specific advice. Links to tutorials and aritcles are welcome as well!

Comment: Okay, while you are answering my question, here's a little simple solution, that I found that will work for me. Of course, it's far from being an optimal solution or even a decent one.

But someone may find it useful.
<body class="<%= @page.template %>">

This will get your page template name and make it your body class.

Similarly, the following code will put your controller name there:
<body class="<%= controller.controller_name %>">

Comment: Haha, here's my solution:

<body class="<%= @page.slug %>">

will do page slug as class for the body. God, I love this language!

Comment: Rails doesn't have built-in "pages". Where does `@page.template` / `@page.slug` come from, i.e. what kind of object is `@page`? A custom active record instance or something from a gem?

Answer (score 0):

">
This works in my case, and it may not work like this in your case. Then try something similar.

Comment: <body class="<%= @page.slug %>">

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).